# toLocaleString() with space between currency and value

Tags: javascript

I'm using a quite simple script to format numbers:

```
gst = '123.45';
currency = 'EUR';

money = gst.toLocaleString('en-US', { 
  style: 'currency', 
  currency: currency, 
  currencyDisplay: 'code'
});
```

this will out put this:
`EUR123.45`

which is, what I want. But I find it kind of ugly that there is no space between the currency and the value. Is there a way to manage this without using a .replace() after the operation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you just use `decimal` formatting, then prepend the resulting string with `'EUR'`? I admit I'm not really sure about your approach: using predefined format, even though it doesn't fit, then adjusting it. )

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I already realized that the problem was caused by another part of my code. The function ist appending and not pretending the currency. Unfortunately I can not delete my post at the moment Oo

Comment: What about now? ) BTW, the code in your question seems to be incorrect; Number should be stored in `gst`, not String.

Comment: I regret my first comment. The problem is occurring, when I use the locale 'en-US'.  Regarding the string: it's only in the example. I get the number from a HTML string and convert it with parseFloat()

Comment: Great explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326209/2044126

Answer (score 0):

I'm positive there is no specification if `toLocaleString` that will do this without the replace.  You either need to prepend or adjust after the `toLocaleString` operation.