# How to get space between currency code and amount using localeString in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, localization, currency

I have to display a number in currency format using the country code with comma and period separators based on the country.

Example if the number is 4294967295000 then

1. USA =   USD 4,294,967,295,000.00
2. INDIA = INR 42,94,96,72,95,000.00

I got it working for India, but for USA I am getting this string but I need space between currency code and number:

```js
var number = 4294967295000;

console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
  style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', currencyDisplay: 'code'
}));     // INR 42,94,96,72,95,000.00

console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', currencyDisplay: 'code'
}));     // USD4,294,967,295,000.00
```

How do I achieve spacing between "USD" and number? I did not see anyting in option parameter regarding space. I can write custom code to add space, but I am trying to see if there is better option for doing the same.

Comment: FWIW, Internet Explorer and Edge both display USD with a space after it.

Answer (score 3):

> I did not see anyting in option parameter regarding space.

So I set off down the rabbit hole.

When you pass options in to `toLocaleString`, it follows a number of steps.  Firstly, it converts your passed in options to a `NumberFormat` object.  It [goes through a series of steps to do so](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-InitializeNumberFormat), one of which is:

> 23. If s is "currency", then
>       a. Let c be converting c to upper case as specified in 6.1.
>       b. Set numberFormat.[[currency]] to c.

That means that whatever you've passed in as the `currency` option, so long as it's a proper currency code, is converted to uppercase and stored in the internal `currency` property on the `NumberFormat` object.

We then see that there are some other [internal properties](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-Intl.NumberFormat-internal-slots) used on a `NumberFormat` - in this case, specifically the `positivePattern` internal slot.  The spec notes:

> The value of these properties must be string values that contain a substring "{number}"; the values within the currency property must also contain a substring "{currency}". The pattern strings must not contain any characters in the General Category “Number, decimal digit" as specified by the Unicode Standard.

IE note that at this point, for a given culture, we've created an object that effectively has a formatting string along the lines of `{currency} {number}`.  Only in Chrome's (at least) case for USD, it is `{currency}{number}`.  Note that in IE and Edge, you get the space after USD, so it's decided on a formatting string of `{currency} {number}`.

Next up, we get to the [actual implementation of formatting the number](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-number-format-functions).  Step 7 says:

> 7. If the value of the numberFormat.[[style]] is "currency", then
>      **a. Let currency be the value of numberFormat.[[currency]].
>
>      b. If numberFormat.[[currencyDisplay]] is "code", then
>
>      i. Let cd be currency.**
>
>      c. Else, if numberFormat.[[currencyDisplay]] is "symbol", then
>      i. Let cd be an ILD string representing currency in short form. If the implementation does not have such a representation of currency, then use currency itself.
>      d. Else, if numberFormat.[[currencyDisplay]] is "name", then
>      i. Let cd be an ILD string representing currency in long form. If the implementation does not have such a representation of currency, then use currency itself.
>      e. **Replace the substring "{currency}" within result with cd**.

emphasis mine, showing the steps taken in this case.

---

**TL;DR** - this behaviour appears to browser dependent, and you'll need to parse and fix the resulting string yourself if you consistently want the space, there's no built-in way to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a reliable pattern that what you want to fix is a three-letter code followed by a digit, and you want to fix that by inserting a space, you could use this regex like this:

```
currencyStr = currencyStr.replace(/^([A-Z]{3})(\d)/, (match, $1, $2) => $1 + ' ' + $2);
```